# Redis storing and querying complex structures

Tags: database-design, redis

I want to store a complex structure as JSON object in a Redis Sorted Set.

```
ZADD "mysetkey" 100 [ {"A":"100"}, {"B":"50"}, {"C":"180"}, {"D":"200"} ] 
ZADD "mysetkey" 101 [ {"A":"10"}, {"B":"50"}, {"C":"70"}, {"D":"200"} ] 
ZADD "mysetkey" 88 [ {"A":"300"}, {"B":"50"}, {"C":"110"}, {"D":"200"} ]
```

Now is there an easy to perform operations or searches on the values stored ?
For example, if I want to get `sumof(A) for all elements` ? Or get all elements that have value of `A < 20 AND value of C  > 100`.

My understanding is that it's not possible because Redis stores everything as String. But wanted to confirm it anyway.

Also, it is possible to achieve this in Redis by using a combination of data structures supported by Redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the functionality that you need in a Lua script. When evaluating Lua script Redis loads `cjson` library among others and this library allows you to parse your JSON to extract values from it. See the `EVAL` command. http://redis.io/commands/eval

A code sample from http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html:

```
json_text = '[ true, { "foo": "bar" } ]'
value = cjson.decode(json_text)
-- Returns: { true, { foo = "bar" } }
```

Mind that Redis evaluates scripts one at a time, and no other clients can run their commands while a script is running, so this might now be suitable for you.